# batch CMD for different versions of windows compatibility

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, compatibility, versions

Good Evening

Ive been searching for some hours looking for a way to test a batch file locally that will need to run on several versions of windows, (NT,2000,XP,7,10)

Ive been searching for CMD.exe versions from each to no avail. Am i looking in the wrong place? or is this not the way forward

Thanks

On a side note, I found interesting Windows 10 CMD holds %OS% variable as Windows_NT ... bizarre, assuming an old feature that was forgotten about?

Comment: Are you trying to get the version of windows they are using?

Comment: `ver` command will show the build version. You can check this page to see  the mapping -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BaliC no thanks, was just something trivial I came across. Pretty sure ver will print windows version. Looking for a way to test my bat on several versions of Windows all on my windows 10 pc

Comment: the only way to do this is to use virtual machines (assuming you want to test all from your 10 installation). VirtualBox is free for use so only thing you need is to find installation  images for the older versions of windows.

Comment: "For testing of internal commands, I keep copies of CMD.EXE of all my previous Windows versions. For ease of use I renamed them cmdNT4.exe, cmdW2K.exe, cmdXP.exe, cmdXP2.exe etcetera. Now if I want to know if an internal command will work in NT 4 I use a command like this:  cmdNT4.exe /K DIR /? Note: Use this trick carefully, the results won't always be identical to the results when run in the full OS. To demonstrate this, run cmdXXX.exe /K VER and compare the version and build numbers to those of the "host" OS' own VER command. " - http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php

Comment: This is what had me wondering the possibilities. Otherwise VM might be the way forward. Thanks

Comment: NT, 2000 and XP are no longer supported. As for the batch file - what are you trying to do and why would the OS version matter? Why not use Powershell? Where will you find a customer that still uses NT 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

using the version is pretty irrelevant. You will notice that when running

```
echo %cmdextversion%
```

it has been `2` since forever. Majority of the commands are still the same on all version of of cmd.exe except if you are going back to the days of `command.com`

The OS changes makes a bit of a difference, but there is a thin line where you can be safe with pretty much any command within a batch file.

for instance, You should not go back to the days of doing `cd C:\Progra~1` instead just wrap the space containing paths in quotes.

But, the real solution to your problem would be to do OS check within your command files and then `goto` matching each OS.

Most `MS-Dos` based commands are still pretty much the same, with the exclusion of newer commands available only on new systems, but again, these can be bypassed by checking `ver` before executing parts of the batch/cmd file.

Here's an example of something that will work on pretty much any windows OS.

```
for /d %%a in ("F:\Program Files\TrendReports\GRP\Hourly\*") do (xcopy /Y "%%a\%datetime%\*." "C:\Temp-stats")
```

Some very old NT systems might not like using `"F:\Program Files"` where the old method of `C:\Progra~1` is still 100% excepted on the latest OS'.

*as a side note on 64 bit windows, `cd C:\Progra~2` will cd to C:\program Files (86)`*

So the point being, you can run any batch file on any Windows OS, if structured correctly and you do ensure that minor changes in certain commands are catered for by checking OS version in the script and following the goto of each OS version.

you can also perhaps check the `ver` and set the version in the script like so:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%x in ('ver') do set WINVER=%%x set WINVER=%WINVER:Version =%
```

Comment: There is no DOS in NT. The short names aren't needed in `.cmd`  batches, they exist only for FAT compatibility. There is no guarantee that any of the short names will be the same from one machine to another. They are generated by FAT.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, the commands are still dos based, hence why I name it that. I am using the short names as examples to prove a point, not to say that is what should be used. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: They aren't. DOS means something very specific. In fact, many of the shell commands you think as "DOS" wouldn't work in a DOS window, eg in Windows Me. One example are the PUSHD/POPD pair

Comment: Would you be happy if he rename it to MS-DOS?

Comment: @JannieVisagie perhaps I should.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you kindly provide an example of the PUSHD/POPD pair you are referring to? I am interested to know what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Love how people vote down a answer for no apparent reason and don't leave cmments.